# Which movie are these images from?

Tags: image-identification

I was recently examining some old photos when I came across three pictures that showed a film in the background.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me in identifying this movie?

My first assumptions were *The Transformers:The Last Knight* or *Rogue One* due to the satellite, but none of them have a scene with the subtitle saying "*Kids hold on*".

My other guesses were something like *2012* or *Battleship*.

Comment: ["Kids, hold on to your seats"](https://www.tzr.io/yarn-clip/62e967e5-736d-4ee4-bb86-54a7a7af4997/gif)

Comment: Why does the third picture look like anime instead of a live-action movie?

Comment: @Medinoc Low color depth?  The human arm in the first image seems to have the same thing going on.

Comment: @Medinoc I thought it was a Matt painting behind the scenery like in Star Wars, but 2016 is in the greenscreen/cgi era.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These images are from *[Independence Day: Resurgence](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1628841/)* (2016).

> [image]
> ["*They're gonna target the cannon first*"](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/9d2fcf0a-38d2-4641-8ceb-4f83723ab56c)

Comment: "They're gonna target the cannon first."  Shows how ignorant the writers are.  You target *the radar* first, so the cannon can't aim as fast and accurately.  *Then* you aim at the cannon.

Comment: @RonJohn Are the writers ignorant, or the *characters*?

Comment: @Barmar the characters are wearing combat armor, and are huddled behind what appears to be a radar station.  I’ve not seen the movie, so don’t know who they’re supposed to be, but  that indicates they’re “military”, and so should know better.  Screen writers knowing squat about the military is a truth of nature which is regularly confirmed (the occasional exception providing the rule).